# Extrude font into a prism: BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics and Line fail to produce a RegionProduct

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, regions

I am attempting to use a text character as the base of a three-dimensional prism:

```
$Version

(* 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023) *)

Echo[rtext = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["1"], _Text], "dim rtext:", RegionDimension];
Echo[rline = Line[{{0}, {1}}], "dim rline:", RegionDimension];

(*
» dim rtext:  2
» dim rline:  1
*)

RegionProduct[rtext, rline]
DiscretizeRegion@%

(*
Unevaluated RegionProduct[ «graphical ‹1›», Line[{{0},{1}}] ]

Error message: DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region RegionProduct[,Line[{{0},{1}}]].

Unevaluated DiscretizeRegion[ RegionProduct[ «graphical ‹1›», Line[{{0},{1}}] ] ]
*)
```

My expectations were:

- a 2D-boundary of the digit I used in `rtext` (`Polygon` or, if the digit shape has "holes", `FilledCurve`) as the result of `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` (that looks fine);
- a 1D-line in `rline`, which also looks fine;
- a 3D-body, a prism, as the result of `RegionProduct`, which didn't happen; and
- a mesh version of the body from `DiscretizeRegion`, which also didn't happen.

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I have done nothing but reading docs, googling, searching SE and trying ever weirder ideas for the past two days and am no closer to a solution. Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks,
Felix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Replace `1` to `1.`
- Since `RegionProduct` is already a `MeshRegion`, so we need not discrete the region again.

```
rtext = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["1"], _Text];
rline = Line[{{0}, {1.}}];
reg = RegionProduct[rtext, rline];
HighlightMesh[reg, Style[2, Directive@{Opacity[.2], LightCyan}]]
```

[image]

- Test `NDSolveFEM`, but `MeshRegion` does not work,I don't know why.

```
(* $Version > 13 *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
rtext = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["1"], _Text];
rline = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[rtext];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[rline];
productMesh = ElementMeshRegionProduct[mesh1, mesh2];
productMesh["Wireframe"] // Show // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

- Add the comment by @user21

```
(*$Version>13*)
Clear[mesh1, mesh2];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
rtext = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["1"], _Text];
rline = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[rtext, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[rline, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
productMesh = ElementMeshRegionProduct[mesh1, mesh2];
MeshRegion[productMesh]
```

Comment: That's because MeshRegion can not deal with the second order Prism elements. Try this: `mesh1 = ToElementMesh[rtext, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[rline, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
productMesh = ElementMeshRegionProduct[mesh1, mesh2];
MeshRegion[productMesh]`

Comment: @user21 Thanks!

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you so much! I have no clue why I must use a machine number as the second `Line` coordinate, or why the `0` can remain an integer. As a (so far) non-FEM-user, I was equally surprised by the connection to FEM and to `NDSolve`, and I look forward to learning more about it. Thank you!

Comment: @user21 Are second-order prism elements ones with curved boundaries? So much to learn – thank you!

Comment: @FelixKasza, yes, curved edges: In the [Details and Options section of PrismElement](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/PrismElement.html) the is an illustration.